# Let users upload file and send to listing user (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently working on a website with the following functionality:
Users(employers) can post job listings. Interested users can click on the job listing, which brings them to an apply page. Here they have to upload their resume via file upload and click on send. The resume is now send to the employers email.
So I got it to work that the email is send to the listing user. I also know how to send my own attachments.
I however cannot get it to work that users upload their own resumes. Right now I want to have them saved locally, and not using a different storage like S3.

Here is the code that I have

listings_controller.rb

```
def send_resume_email
        @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
        @user = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
        UserMailer.new_resume(@user, @listing).deliver
        redirect_to findjobs_path, notice: 'Message sent'
    end
```

user_mailer.rb

```
def new_resume(user, listing)
    @listing = listing
    @user = user
    attachments['header.png'] = File.read("#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/header.png", mode:     "rb")
    @url = 'http://www.example.com'
    mail(to: listing.user.email, subject: 'Thanks for the awesome site')

end
```

apply.html.erb

```
<div class="top">
<div class="container-content">
    <div class="container">
        <%= form_tag(listing_send_resume_email_path, :html => { :multipart => true}) do %>

           <%= file_field_tag :file %>
           <%= submit_tag nil, class: 'btn btn-default btn-about pull-right' %>
       <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload a file you can use

1.Paperclip gem https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

or

2.Carrierwave gem https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave

and they both support S3

There's a nice screencast using carrierwave which might help http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads

Comment: I have the paperclip gem installed already but I don't find how others can upload images. Also, I would like to store images locally, not in S3